# How do I recognize "/" in string?

Tags: java, string

I've used

```
String[] red = linija.split("(?!^)");
```

and now in this String array I want to know if `red[0]` is `"/"`. Tried `(red[0] == "/")` and with `"//"`, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `red[0].equals("/")` ?